# Excel adding values from columns that start with the same word?

Tags: excel, vba

My colleagues at work seem to spend a lot of time getting data from spreadsheets and having to work out percentages then paste it into a report.

I'm pretty sure there is a quicker way but it's proving difficult with little experience with Ecxel.

[Excel Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPluD.jpg)

I have already created a Macro to remove any unnecessary text in the fields so it is now just a value.

My problem is that there is always a different number of fields that I need to get data from.

The field I need the values from is the one directly under any field that starts with "Unique Pulls" Once I can work this out, the rest should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just starting out with VBA myself so not 100% sure, but perhaps you could use a Find/FindNext loop?

This might be helpful on using Find/FindNext (example in 'Section 3'): http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Hope that helps with getting you started!

---

*edit:*

Maybe you've already solved this from the comments above, but in case you are still having issues with adding up values here's a potential solution I've been playing with: all credit to @Alex K. for the `UCase$(cell.Value)` suggestion above!

```
Dim LastRow As Integer, LastCol As Integer
Dim iTotal As Integer, n As Integer, i As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

For n = 2 To LastRow         ' For each row with data...
    iTotal = 0               ' Resets total count for each row.
    For i = 1 To LastCol     ' Find each column starting with 'Unique Pulls'.

        If UCase$(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value) Like "UNIQUE PULLS*" Then
            iTotal = iTotal + ActiveSheet.Cells(n, i).Value
               ' For each of these columns, take value and add to total sum
        End If

        Next i    ' Move onto next column
        ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 5).Value = iTotal
            'REPLACE 5 WITH COLUMN NUMBER OF TOTAL PULLS
    Next n        ' Move onto next row
```

Perhaps?

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Works a treat, thank you

Comment: It worked fine on the test sheet that I had it on, but soon as I tried to run it on a real test if came up an error on line 13.

Comment: iTotal = iTotal + ActiveSheet.Cells(n, i).Value

Is the line showing the error

Comment: Hmm are there any cells which don't contain numbers there? e.g. text mixed in. Also what type of error is it showing?

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://imgcloud.co.uk/error.jpg). This is the error that it is showing, I can't see any cells that are empty or have text in..

Comment: That does sound like something is mismatching with the variable iTotal (since declared as an integer). When you try to run it and the error pops up, has it started writing into some of the rows in 'Total Pulls'? - it should calculate up to the row it has a problem with...

Answer (score 0):

This looks at each header in A:A and msgboxes the value under any cell beginning with your search text:

```
Dim cell As Range: Set cell = Range("A1")

Do While cell.Value <> ""
    If UCase$(cell.Value) Like "UNIQUE PULLS*" Then
        MsgBox cell.Offset(1, 0).Value
    End If

    Set cell = cell.Offset(0, 1)
Loop
```

Comment: This is sort of what I need, but instead of a MsgBox, I need it to display into another cell so I can then work out the percentages from the total amount.

Comment: Something like `range("B5").Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value`

Comment: I've got it to display in the cell but it is adding the values up incorrectly, it is just displaying 2 rather than adding them all together and displaying.